# tempusdominus bootstrap 4 icons are missing

Tags: javascript, .net, bootstrap-4, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

The tempusdominus bootstrap 4 icons are missing in my ASP.NET MVC application.
Here are the screenshots of how it looks:

[image: date]
[image: time]

These are the following scripts and css that are being loaded in (based of [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/3cqL9t3x/)):

```
bootstrap.css (4.0.0-alpha.6)
font-awesome.min.css (4.7.0)
tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css (5.1.2)
bootstrap.min.js (4.0.0-alpha.6)
jquery-3.3.1.min.js (3.3.1) 
moment-with-locales.min.js (2.18.1)
tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js (5.1.2)
tether.min.js (1.4.0)
```

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  Font-Awesome CSS in your HEAD tag:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Font-Awesome is in the head tag of the page.

Comment: However, I am using a local version of the file, could that be the problem?